# How to prevent command window from closing when a program finishes executing

Tags: python, command-line, py2exe, command-window

I made a small program in Python (.py) and converted it into a Windows executable file (.exe) using Py2exe. It asks for a string and then outputs a string -- very simple! -- and works flawlessly in Python.

However, when the exe file finishes execution in the command window, the command window closes automatically before I can get a glimpse of its output (I assume it does print the output because, like I said, it works flawlessly in Python).

How can I prevent this from happening? I assume I need to change my code, but what exactly do I need to add to it?

Here is my code, in case it helps you to see it (it's a word-wrapper):

```
import string

def insertNewlines(text, lineLength):
    if text == '':
        return ''
    elif len(text) <= lineLength:
        return text
    elif text[lineLength] == ' ':
        return text[:lineLength] + '\n' + insertNewlines(text[lineLength+1:], lineLength)
    elif text[lineLength-1] == ' ':
        return text[:lineLength] + '\n' + insertNewlines(text[lineLength:], lineLength)
    else:
        if string.find(text, ' ', lineLength) == -1:
            return text
        else:
            return text[:string.find(text,' ',lineLength)+1] + '\n' + insertNewlines(text[string.find(text,' ',lineLength)+1:], lineLength)
    print

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = str(raw_input("Enter text to word-wrap: "))
    lineLength = int(raw_input("Enter number of characters per line: "))
    print 
    print insertNewlines(text, lineLength)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can always just add raw_input() at the end of the program, so you have to press enter to exit the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use `raw_input()` just before your program finishes. It will wait until you hit enter before closing.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = str(raw_input("Enter text to word-wrap: "))
    lineLength = int(raw_input("Enter number of characters per line: "))
    print 
    print insertNewlines(text, lineLength)
    raw_input()
```

Comment: Thanks! Also I realize when the exe version runs, and asks user for input, user can't paste in text using the right-click of the mouse (command prompt is unresponsive to right-clicking). So, the user has to type the text by hand. Do you have any idea why this might happen? Thanks again.

Comment: You can paste text to the command prompt by right clicking the menu bar, then choosing 'edit' followed by 'paste'.

Comment: Yeah, annoying windows cmd.exe thing.

Comment: Actually, @wim, this has _nothing_ to do with `cmd.exe`, that's just a command interpreter. I think the culprit you're looking for is the console subsystem (or CSRSS or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

Just put this at the end of your code:

```
junk = raw_input ("Hit ENTER to exit: ")
```

In other words, your `main` segment should be:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = str(raw_input("Enter text to word-wrap: "))
    lineLength = int(raw_input("Enter number of characters per line: "))
    print 
    print insertNewlines(text, lineLength)
    junk = raw_input ("Press ENTER to continue: ")
```

Comment: I prefer to write "Press Enter to continue..." or similar, because the oppositeness of 'enter' to 'exit' makes the prompt seem awkwardly worded

Comment: @wim: So I'm not the only one who finds myself looking for the "Exit" key? :)

Comment: @wim, you mean like pressing the Start button to shut down Windows? :-) I'll defer to your judgement.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my scripts:

```
#### windows only ####
import msvcrt

def readch(echo=True):
    "Get a single character on Windows."
    while msvcrt.kbhit():
        msvcrt.getch()
    ch = msvcrt.getch()
    while ch in b'\x00\xe0':
        msvcrt.getch()
        ch = msvcrt.getch()
    if echo:
        msvcrt.putch(ch)
    return ch.decode()

def pause(prompt='Press any key to continue . . .'):
    if prompt:
        print prompt,
    readch()
######################
```

Sometimes though, I just use the following to make the window stay open for a short time before closing.

```
import time
time.sleep(3)
```